# Does this series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n)^2(-1)^n} {1+(n^2)} $ diverge or converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n)^2(-1)^n} {1+(n^2)} $$

Like every absolutely convergent series are convergent i am working on:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n)^2} {1+(n^2)} $$

The ratio test gives me:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{1+(n+1)^2}}{\frac{(n)^2}{1+(n)^2}}$ = 1

Wich is inconclusive. Then i take the limit:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n)^2} {1+(n^2)} $= 1
 That is different to zero.
So i can conclude that this series diverges .
What do you think? Is this correct?

Comment: Seems good. Series diverges.

Comment: *NB:* $(n)^2=(n^2)=n^2$.

Answer (score 3):

If a series converges the the lim of the sequence is zero, so this series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

The series is diverge but your proof is not correct because a series which is not absolutely convergent can also be convergent (conditionally convergent).

Comment: For a series $\sum a_n$, if $a_n\not\to 0$ then it neither converges conditionally or absolutely, it is guaranteed to be divergent. So if you show that $a_n \not\to 0$, then it is enough to conclude divergence.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n n^2}{1+n^2}$$
is neither conditionally or absolutely convergent since the absolute value of the main term does not tend to zero as $n\to +\infty$. On the other hand it is Cesàro-summable:
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n n^2}{1+n^2}e^{-\varepsilon n}=-\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{1+n^2}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\pi}{\sinh \pi}-1\right). $$
The last identity can be seen as a consequence of the Poisson summation formula, the (inverse) Laplace transform or just Herglotz' trick.

Answer (score 0):

We may rewrite it as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n)^2(-1)^n} {1+(n^2)}{=-{1\over 2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n)^2} {1+(2n)^2}-\frac{(2n+1)^2} {1+(2n+1)^2}\\=-{1\over 2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1} {1+(2n+1)^2}-\frac{1} {1+(2n)^2}\\=-{1\over 2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-4n-1} {(1+(2n+1)^2)(1+(2n)^2)}}$$which converges for sure since $$\frac{-4n-1} {(1+(2n+1)^2)(1+(2n)^2)}\sim -{1\over 4n^3}$$for large enough $n$.

Comment: This method is often a good one for convergence of an alternating series.  But to finish, you would need to show that the single term goes to zero, which fails here.

Comment: No need to that. Only a simple comparison test works here.

Comment: Your argument shows that the two limits$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{(n)^2(-1)^n} {1+(n^2)},\qquad
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} \frac{(n)^2(-1)^n} {1+(n^2)}
$$
both exist, but not that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ exists.

Comment: Surely not. As the series has been defined as $\sum (-1)^n a_n=-(a_1-a_2)-(a_2-a_3)-(a_3-a_4)-\cdots$ I defined $b_n=-(a_{2n-1}-a_{2n})$ therefore $$\sum b_n=-(a_1-a_2)-(a_2-a_3)-(a_3-a_4)-\cdots=\sum (-1)^na_n$$

Comment: And thus we see that "grouping" of a divergent series may produce a convergent series.  Another example: $1-1+1-1+1-1+\dots$.

Comment: But the series you introduced is not convergent. It oscillates between $0$ and $1$. Also I considered each term with the next one which doesn't make any problem...

Answer (score 0):

Further remark on Mostafa's answer.
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{(n)^2(-1)^n} {1+(n^2)}=
\frac{-\pi+\sinh \pi}{2\sinh \pi} \approx 0.36,
\\
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} \frac{(n)^2(-1)^n} {1+(n^2)}=
\frac{-\pi-\sinh \pi}{2\sinh \pi} \approx -0.64.
$$
These do not agree, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ does not exist.

Comment: Let me have a question, how did you determin the result of the first limsum? Because I get the same result but for the original sum. (I started from $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\big(1-\frac{1} {1+(n^2)}\big)$, then separated the sum odd and even parts, using partial fractions and integration.)

Answer (score 0):

It's *definitely* divergent, that one, because the terms become closer to 1 in magnitude with increasing $n$; the sum becomes more & more like just alternating beween adding & subtracting 1 as in increases.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{N \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}}$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{n^{2}\pars{-1}^{n} \over 1 + n^{2}} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor N/2\right\rfloor}
{4n^{2} \over 1 + 4n^{2}} -
\sum_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor\pars{N - 1}/2\right\rfloor}
{\pars{2n + 1}^{2} \over 1 + \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = \left\lfloor\pars{N - 1}/2\right\rfloor + 1}^{\left\lfloor N/2\right\rfloor}
{4n^{2} \over 1 + 4n^{2}}
\\[5mm] &\
+\ \underbrace{\sum_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor\pars{N - 1}/2\right\rfloor}
\bracks{{4n^{2} \over 1 + 4n^{2}} - {\pars{2n + 1}^{2} \over 1 + \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}}}
_{\ds{\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\LARGE\to}\
-\,{1 + \pi\csc\pars{\pi} \over 2}}}
\end{align}

> Note that

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = \left\lfloor\pars{N - 1}/2\right\rfloor + 1}^{\left\lfloor N/2\right\rfloor}
{4n^{2} \over 1 + 4n^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{{4\pars{m - 1}^{2} \over
1 + 4\pars{m - 1}^{2}}  +
{4m^{2} \over 1 + 4m^{2}}} & \mbox{if} & 
\ds{N}\ even,\ \ds{N \equiv 2m}
\\[2mm]
\ds{4m^{2} \over 1 + 4m^{2}} & \mbox{if} & 
\ds{N}\ \phantom{n}odd,\ \ds{N \equiv 2m + 1}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm] \implies &\
\lim_{N \to \infty}\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = \left\lfloor\pars{N - 1}/2\right\rfloor + 1}^{\left\lfloor N/2\right\rfloor}
{4n^{2} \over 1 + 4n^{2}}}\
\mbox{doesn't}\ exist.
\end{align}